# Flat coordinates of a Riemannian metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

We know that, given a metric $g_{ij}(p)$ on a $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, if the metric has vanishing Riemannian curvature, then there exists a coordinate system in which it is constant.

Let $(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ be the coordinates of a local chart for $M$, and $g_{ij}(x)$ the noncostant **flat** metric in this system of coordinates.

Which are the techniques one can use to explicitly find a new system of coordinates $(\tilde{x}^1,\ldots,\tilde{x}^n)$ in which the metric is constant, say $\tilde{g}_{ab}(\tilde{x})=\tilde{g}_{ab}^0$?

I realise that in principle one may try and solve the system of equations
$\tilde{g}_{ab}^0=\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial\tilde{x}^a}\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial\tilde{x}^b}g_{lm}(x)$, for the functions $x=x(\tilde{x})$but it seems quite impossible even for $n=2$, let aside in higher dimension.

Comment: When you say "explicit", do you assume we have the original atlas of maps $\{ f_j \}_{j\in I}$ from $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ to the manifold?

Comment: I should probably have been more precise: I am interested just in a chart, and of course I have the flat metric written wrt the coordinates in one ("bad") chart

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you rephrase it in the question itself?

Comment: If you can find a point $p$ for which you can compute all the geodesics that emanate from $p$, then you get the normal coordinates around $p$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates Since you're assuming the metric in your chart to be isometric to some Euclidean $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, it follows that the normal coordinates establish an isometry between a neighbourhood of $p$ in $M$ and a neighbourhood of the origin in $T_pM$. Now you only need to choose a cartesian coordinate system in $T_pM$.

Comment: You have an explicit formula for $g$ and you want an explicit formula for the change in coordinates?

Comment: You can't get an explicit formula for flat coordinates without doing some integration, but you can reduce the problem to integrating a Frobenius system of *linear* first-order equations, rather than the nonlinear system you wrote down at the end.  However, even in dimension $2$, you can't avoid having to solve ODE that cannot, in the general case, be integrated by quadrature.